# Django forms - How i make a ModelChoiceField to show data only if another select value is selected

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I have a select witch contains over 50.000 options. When I access the page I need to wait 3 s to load that page because of that... I must to find a solution to use another select to filter that select or to not load all data when i access the page. Can anyone give me some advice?

Comment: You can add an input (above or next to the select) to type in to filter the data and populate the select based on that. It could return for example max 10 results. Or you can consider using [select2](https://select2.org/) or something similar.

Comment: in select2 can i set a max values?

Comment: I would put the limit in the database query.